# struts2 iterator tag - iterating over a collection of collections

Tags: struts2

I am new to struts 2 and am losing my mind over iterating a collection of collections in my JSP using the iterator tag.

My action class exposes a List (parent) which in turn contains 4 more lists (children). Each child list contains 5 domain objects (`e.g. User`).

In my JSP, i need to display the User.Name after iterating over the collections. I am able to iterate over the parent collection but cannot get to the child lists. They are anonymous lists and are not exposed by a specific name (i.e. a getter is not available).

```
    <s:iterator value="usrList" var="refParent">
    <ul>
        <s:iterator value="#refParent.columns" var="usr">
        <li>
            <s:property value="#usr.Name"/>
        </li>
        </s:iterator>   
    </ul>
</s:iterator>
```

The outer iterator results in 4 `<ul>` tags but each of those tags are empty i.e. none of the `<li>` tags are displayed.

All the examples that i see are accessing specific named Collections (e.g. `User.PhoneList`) but none of them seem to demonstrate this particular behavior.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What do you mean, they're "anonymous lists"? How do you access the lists in Java? It's the same in JSP.

Comment: Did you try "#usr.name"? I seldom require var attributes. You should be able to remove the var on the outer iterator, on the inner use "columns" as the value, you can also drop the var on the inner iterator and in the property simply use "name" or if it is something like a list of built in types then just use an empty property tag (it will use what is at the top of the stack).

Comment: @Dave: By anonymous lists, i mean that my second collection is not a named property. My structure is basically a List1 (parent) which contains 4 Lists (List2) which are added to List1 using the `add` method and then List2 collections contain my domain objects that i am trying to access in my JSP.

Comment: Then it's a simple nested list; I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: @Dave: I am sure it is simple, i am just not able to get it syntactically right in the JSP. I am trying to work using the examples that i find but in all the cases the examples show using a named property e.g. the first collection is that of "Animals" and it contains a collection of "Dogs" and they are able to access the second collection using `#animal.dogs`. I am going to try Quaternion's suggestion.

Comment: Have you resolved the problem of iterator tag with optgroup.

Answer (score 1):

I think i finally figured it out from one of the Iterator-tag examples (thanks to Umesh and Quaternion). I totally missed that one and did not read through the entire example using `top`.

```
   <s:iterator value="usrList">
     <ul>
        <s:iterator value="top">
         <li>
            <s:property value="Name"/>
         </li>
        </s:iterator>   
    </ul>
  </s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this example from **[this link](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-iterator-tag-example/)**

```
<table>
<s:iterator value="allCities" id="cities">
    <s:iterator value="#city.phoneNumbers" id="number">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <!-- Accessing the city name through the city variable -->
            <s:property value="#city.name" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <!-- Accessing the objects inside the phone number object through the number variable -->
            <s:property value="#number.prefix" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <s:property value="#number.rate" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Struts2 Iterator tag a simple enough and work in a very simple manner.So if you have Collection of Collection or what ever structure think how you will iterator them in a simple Java application , same will apply for the S2 iterator tag, but at same time it will give you more flexibility as well configurations.

In Short you need nested iterator tag.When S2 iterator tag iterate objects it will place current object on the top of value stack and you can easily access that tag in your JSP code.

Since in your code Top level object will be a Collection you need to iterate that again like

```
<s:iterator value="firstCollection">
 <s:iterator value="firstCollection>
    / do what you want here
  </iterator>
```

Since while iterating object will be at top of stack you can refer to that tag directly without any reference.

i Suggest you to have look at following official documents

1. [iterator](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/iterator.html)
2. [iterator-tag-examples](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/iterator-tag-examples.html)